# Should !ruby/symbol in Ruby l10n YAML files be translated

Tags: ruby, localization, internationalization, yaml, symbols

I have come across the following snippet in a Ruby YAML file which is to be localized.

```
 order:
      - !ruby/symbol day
      - !ruby/symbol month
      - !ruby/symbol year
```

So, my question is whether I should localize "day", "month" and "year" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, you should not.
Long answer: Unless you're localizing some sort of source-code-processing software or something, which does need translation for some reason. (What? Anything's possible, no!)

Those are [Ruby symbols serialized to YAML format](http://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#symbols). Like:

```
[:day, :month, :year]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get it. Normally, ruby symbols should not be localized :)